# Django unique_together from abstract model field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Suppose I have an Abstract Model:

```
class SoftDelete(models.Model):
    _active = models.NullBooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

And a model that inerhits from this abstract model:

```
class SomeModel(AbstractModel):
    some_field = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('_active', 'some_field')
```

Here I've constrained `some_field` with the `_active` field by using unique_together, which is used by a soft-delete feature I have.

That works and all but, every model I have an unique constraint now needs to apply `_active` into the uniqueness since when deleted it's not really deleted, only `_active = None`.

**My question is**, since all my models will inerhit from `SoftDelete` is there an efficient way of applying `_active` to all models that have in their Metas an unique_together constraint? Instead of manually adding it and maybe forget of it.

I was hoping to add something like bellow to abstract's Meta class:

```
For unique_together in child_unique_together:
    unique_together.append('_active')
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I used the hard way and implemented the unique together model by model since I couldn't find a better solution.